# pushing data to an array in angular causes non consistent scroll effects on div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Explaining my code, when user scrolls to the bottom of the div, new data is pushed to `array1` and the scroll bar is also pushed above the new data so the user would have to scroll past the new data to reach the bottom of the div again.

However, when the user scrolls to the top of the div, data is pushed to the array but the scroll bar stays at the very top of the div meaning the user would not even know if new data has been even loaded.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

I want the scroll effect of scrolling to the bottom ( where the scrollbar moves along with an array push) to be the same as if were to scroll to the top of the div. So the user scrolls the top and new data is loaded and the scroll bar gets pushed down based on the new data.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Angular Test</title>
</head>
<style>
  .frame{
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    background-color: gray;
    overflow-y:scroll;
  }
</style>
<body>

  <div class="frame" ng-controller="publicCtrl" id="frame">
    <div class="posts">
      <p class="post" ng-repeat="obj in array1 track by $index">{{obj}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var myAppModule = angular.module('app', []);
  myAppModule.controller('publicCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.message="hi";
    $scope.array1 = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
      $scope.array1.push($scope.message="hi");
   }
   var wrapper = document.getElementById('frame');
   wrapper.onscroll = function (evt){
     //detect when scroll has reached the top of the frame
     if(wrapper.scrollTop === 0){
       console.log('top of frame');
       for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
         $scope.array1.push($scope.message="hi");
      }
      $scope.$apply();

     }

     //detect when scroll has reached the bottom of the frame
     if(wrapper.scrollHeight - wrapper.scrollTop === wrapper.clientHeight){
        console.log('bottom of frame');
        for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
          $scope.array1.push($scope.message="hi");
       }
       $scope.$apply();
     }
   }

   $timeout(function(){
     wrapper.scrollTop += 120;
   },0);

  }]);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this in plain javascript or Angularjs?

Please test my code if I am not making sense.

Comment: You can move the scroll bar to the bottom when scroll bar reaches top. No need to push data when scroll bar reaches top. As you move the scroll bar to the bottom, you achieve both loading data and maintaining scrollbar position to newly pushed data.

Comment: not very efficient, is there a way to move it based of how much new content gets added?